# How do deal with h2 databases inability to deal with interrupts

Tags: java, database, h2

How do deal with h2 database inability to deal with interrupts, I was occasionally seeing that my embedded h2 database appeared to get corrupted, in particular I had amended an ExecutorService so that if a task took too long it would cancel the task. The task would be cancelled okay but then subsequent database access failed with exceptions such as

```
23/07/2019 14.23.31:BST:DeleteDuplicatesController:start:SEVERE: commit failed
org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187)
    at com.jthink.songkong.db.ReportCache.save(ReportCache.java:46)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.AbstractReport.setReportDatabaseObject(AbstractReport.java:365)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.DeleteDuplicatesReport.setReportDatabaseObject(DeleteDuplicatesReport.java:333)
    at com.jthink.songkong.reports.DeleteDuplicatesReport.closeReport(DeleteDuplicatesReport.java:377)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.toplevelanalyzer.DeleteDuplicatesController.deleteAnyDups(DeleteDuplicatesController.java:606)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.toplevelanalyzer.DeleteDuplicatesController.start(DeleteDuplicatesController.java:665)
    at com.jthink.songkong.ui.swingworker.DeleteDuplicates.doInBackground(DeleteDuplicates.java:43)
    at com.jthink.songkong.ui.swingworker.DeleteDuplicates.doInBackground(DeleteDuplicates.java:20)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from nio:C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Roaming/SongKong/Database/Database.mv.db failed; file length -1 read length 4096 at 1541494 [1.4.199/1]"; SQL statement:
COMMIT [50000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:280)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:542)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.commit(NewProxyConnection.java:1284)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from nio:C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Roaming/SongKong/Database/Database.mv.db failed; file length -1 read length 4096 at 1541494 [1.4.199/1]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883)
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.readFully(DataUtils.java:420)
    at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.readFully(FileStore.java:98)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readBufferForPage(MVStore.java:1048)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2186)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:554)
    at org.h2.mvstore.Page$NonLeaf.getChildPage(Page.java:1086)
    at org.h2.mvstore.Page.get(Page.java:221)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.get(MVMap.java:402)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.get(MVMap.java:389)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getMapName(MVStore.java:2737)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.renameMap(MVStore.java:2650)
    at org.h2.mvstore.tx.TransactionStore.commit(TransactionStore.java:453)
    at org.h2.mvstore.tx.Transaction.commit(Transaction.java:389)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:691)
    at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:46)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:133)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:267)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:110)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:721)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileNio.read(FilePathNio.java:74)
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.readFully(DataUtils.java:406)
    ... 34 more
23/07/2019 14.23.31:BST:Errors:addError:SEVERE: Adding Error:commit failed
```

[I have since found this issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/227)

Basically if using H2 in embedded mode, and it receives an interrupt then all subsequent access fails until the thread pool is close and reopened. In the example I give of a process having to be cancelled because it appears to be stuck there is no solution except for interrupting

I also have another case whereby usually the controller thread that doesn't directly do a database work itself so I was struggling to see why when an interrupt occurred why this would cause database errors since this is handled by controller thread. I have now worked out the issue is that Im using an ExecutorService with a fixed size BlockingQueue (so that we dont have a big queue build up in memory), but if the queue gets full then new task is actually executed by the controller thread (because of CallerRunsPolicy), so the controller thread can be making calls to database after all.

Im using H2 with hibernate and in both cases calling the following immediately after the interrupt

```
   HibernateUtil.closeFactory();
```

seems to solve the issue, however I guess this means that any other threads with hibernate sessions will be broken, but at least newly opened sessins will be okay. So im not particularly happy with this workaround, any other ideas ?

Using H2 as a server is not a solution since the whole point of H2 was an embedded db self contained within application.

Comment: What exactly does “interrupt occurred“ mean? Show some code. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BasilBourque It means the thread was interrupted, i,e. threw a ThreadInterruptedException

Comment: Post these clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. And explain how/why the thread exceptions are happening.

Comment: I have explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not properly documented using the **async** protocol allows a connection to be interrupted without breaking all other connections.